# Navigator.pop makes an error "Failed assertion: line 4989 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true." in flutter code

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, navigation

Have tried to add a list in bottom sheet and implemented it successfully. But after tries to close the bottom dialog sheet shows an error "Failed assertion: line 4989 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true".. Anyone have any idea about this?

Code :

```
Expanded(
                    child: SizedBox(
                  height: AppMargin.dm_350,
                  child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
                    return Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: AppMargin.dm_20,
                      ),
                      child: Scrollbar(
                        interactive: true,
                        thumbVisibility: true, //always show scrollbar
                        thickness: AppMargin.dm_10, //width of scrollbar
                        radius: Radius.circular(AppMargin.dm_20), //corner radius of scrollbar
                        scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                                Theme(
                                      data: Theme.of(context)
                                          .copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
                                      child: CustomExpansionTile(
                                        title: BasicText(
                                            text: list[i].name!,
                                            textColor: AppColor.black,
                                            fontSize: AppMargin.dm_17,
                                            fontWeight: AppFont.fontWeightSemiBold),
                                        initiallyExpanded: true,
                                        trailing: SizedBox.shrink(),
                                        children: [
                                            Column(
                                              children: list[i].occupationsResponseDto!.map((data) => RadioListTile(
                                                        title: Text(data.name!,
                                                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                                                        visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                                          horizontal:
                                                              VisualDensity.minimumDensity + 2,
                                                          vertical:
                                                              VisualDensity.minimumDensity + 2,
                                                        ),
                                                        groupValue: initialValue,
                                                        value: data.id!,
                                                        onChanged: (val) {
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            initialValue = data.id!;
                                                            print(data.name);
                                                            Navigator.pop<OccupationsResponseDto>(context, data);
                                                          });
                                                        },
                                                      ))
                                                  .toList(),
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ))
```